# QueryDWORDValue returns 0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, registry

I am using CRegKey to retreive a DWORD value from registry. The code below returns 0 (buf is zero), but the actual value in registry is 1354357483.

```
CRegKey reg;
reg.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", KEY_READ);
DWORD buf;
DWORD s = reg.QueryDWORDValue("InstallDate", buf);
if (s == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    reg.QueryDWORDValue("InstallDate", buf);
    cout << hex << buf;
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with character sets but so far I could not find the solution. My project character settings are set to "Not Set". I tried with Unicode and using wide strings to no avail.

Also a followup question, is there good way to read binary data from registry and casting it to std::string? Data addition/loss is not really a problem for what I am trying to do.

Comment: It is reading the correct value.  Backgrounder [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there any way I can read the value that I see in regedit from a 32bit application?

Comment: Look at the left.  Click "Accessing an Alternate Registry View".

Comment: This is indeed the problem and I was able to solve it using KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag as third parameter. There is just one more thing I am not 100% sure about. What happens if the program is run on 32bit machine? Will the flag simply get ignored and it will read 32bit registry?

Also, please answer the question so I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans Passant was correct. My program was reading the 32bit version of registry while regedit was showing the 64bit version which is why the values did not match. Adding the KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag to read the intended registry solved the problem.